# CSS3/HTML5 Frameworks, specifically for layout

Tags: html, web-applications, user-interface, css

I have been looking at CSS3/HTML5 frameworks available, but there is simply too many to make a decision quickly, and they all seem to be focused on streamlining javascript development and UI elements.

In particular, a very useful part of a framework would be to create CSS-based layouts quickly - without having to worry about browser compatibility. However, without actually using the existing frameworks it seems impossible to understand whether the existing frameworks do that, or how they do it.

For example, I would like to create a simple layout that fills the whole page but has a minimum height/width. This should be a 5-line CSS declaration but it's a headache because of IE. Ideally a good framework would allow me to define this once, instead of adding in a special solution for every browser.

Which of the existing frameworks address this? I'm not talking necessarily about frameworks (as the meaning of 'framework' is somewhat loose when talking about HTML/CSS) but other things that you find helpful in development.

I have looked at column-layout frameworks like 960.gs or blueprint but they seem to be geared toward website development, rather than web application development.

Thanks,

Comment: I've used blueprint in web applications. What do you mean by "geared toward web application development"?

Comment: @jrummell: I mean, suited for laying out a lot of text, or mixed-content, rather than UI elements that have to do a lot of floating.

Answer (score 0):

960 sounds right up your alley. http://960.gs/  you can tie it with adapt.js to make it adaptive. http://adapt.960.gs/

personally if i have to use a css framework, i'll go with oocss https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki  but i think 960 is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I do not want to use 960 because I don't find the column-grid layout very useful - my designs are simple layouts with 3-5 sections but have to flow properly and mix percentages/pixels - much like a desktop application would. All the examples on 960's page are column-based websites with many pages which is not what I need.